# Can I Programatically Modify the IDE's Context Menu's?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, ide, vb.net-2010, visual-studio-macros

I am trying to create an additional menu item for the "Project and Solutions Context Menus>Solution" menu. However, I wanted this context menu to appear ONLY when a certain solution was opened, otherwise I don't want it to show.  I figured I could use the MACROS within the Visual Studio IDE. There are events that run on the opening of solutions & projects, etc.

My question is, can I create the Context Menu I want programatically, point it to the MACRO I want it to run, and then programatically attach it to the CONTEXT menu inside the IDE that I want to display it in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer to my question.  I used the following code to create the menu items I needed:

```
Private WithEvents _objSolutionExplorer_ContextMenu_ItemHandler As EnvDTE.CommandBarEvents
Private _objHash_ContextMenuItemHandlers As New Hashtable

Private Function CreateContextMenuButtonItem(ByVal p_objMenuItem As Object, ByVal p_strMenuItemCaption As String) As CommandBarButton
    '************************************************************************
    ' Procedure/Function: CreateContextMenuButtonItem()
    ' Author: Ben Santiago
    ' Created On: 08/18/2011
    ' Description:
    '       Creates specified MenuButton item.
    '************************************************************************

    '***************************************
    ' Initialize Variables
    '***************************************
    Dim objMenuButton As CommandBarButton
    Dim objClickEventHandler As EnvDTE.CommandBarEvents

    '***************************************
    ' If MenuItem Exists, Delete It
    '***************************************
    For intCounter As Integer = 1 To p_objMenuItem.Controls.Count
        If p_objMenuItem.Controls.Item(intCounter).Caption = p_strMenuItemCaption Then
            p_objMenuItem.Controls.Item(intCounter).Delete()
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
    If EnvironmentEvents._objHash_ContextMenuItemHandlers.Contains(p_strMenuItemCaption) Then
        EnvironmentEvents._objHash_ContextMenuItemHandlers.Remove(p_strMenuItemCaption)
    End If

    '***************************************
    ' Create New Menu Item w/ Click Event Handling
    '***************************************
    objNewMenuItem = p_objMenuItem.Controls.Add(MsoControlType.msoControlButton, System.Reflection.Missing.Value, System.Reflection.Missing.Value, 1, True)
    objNewMenuItem.Caption = p_strMenuItemCaption
    objClickEventHandler = DTE.Events.CommandBarEvents(objNewMenuItem)
    AddHandler objClickEventHandler.Click, AddressOf TestScoring_objSolutionExplorer_ContextMenu_ItemHandler_Click
    If EnvironmentEvents._objHash_ContextMenuItemHandlers.Contains(p_strMenuItemCaption) Then
        EnvironmentEvents._objHash_ContextMenuItemHandlers.Remove(p_strMenuItemCaption)
    End If
    EnvironmentEvents._objHash_ContextMenuItemHandlers.Add(p_strMenuItemCaption, objClickEventHandler)

    '***************************************
    ' Return Reference To MenuButton Item
    '***************************************
    Return objNewMenuItem
End Function

Private Function CreateContextMenuPopupItem(ByVal p_strCommandBarName As String, ByVal p_strMenuCaption As String) As CommandBarPopup
    '************************************************************************
    ' Procedure/Function: CreateContextMenuPopupItem()
    ' Author: Ben Santiago
    ' Created On: 08/18/2011
    ' Description:
    '       Creates specified MenuPopup item.
    '************************************************************************

    '***************************************
    ' Initialize Variables
    '***************************************
    Dim objCommandBar As CommandBar = DTE.CommandBars(p_strCommandBarName)
    Dim objMenuPopup As CommandBarPopup

    '***************************************
    ' Search For Existing ContextMenuPopup
    '***************************************
    For intCounter As Integer = 1 To objCommandBar.Controls.Count
        If objCommandBar.Controls.Item(intCounter).Caption = p_strMenuCaption Then
            objMenuPopup = objCommandBar.Controls.Item(intCounter)
            Exit For
        End If
    Next

    If objMenuPopup Is Nothing Then
        '***************************************
        ' Create Menu If Needed
        '***************************************
        objMenuPopup = objCommandBar.Controls.Add(MsoControlType.msoControlPopup, System.Reflection.Missing.Value, System.Reflection.Missing.Value, 1, True)
        objMenuPopup.Caption = p_strMenuCaption
    Else
        '***************************************
        ' Delete All Child Menu Items
        '***************************************
        For intCounter As Integer = objMenuPopup.Controls.Count To 1 Step -1
            If EnvironmentEvents._objHash_ContextMenuItemHandlers.Contains(objMenuPopup.Controls.Item(intCounter).Caption) Then
                EnvironmentEvents._objHash_ContextMenuItemHandlers.Remove(objMenuPopup.Controls.Item(intCounter).Caption)
            End If
            objMenuPopup.Controls.Item(intCounter).Delete()
        Next
    End If

    '***************************************
    ' Return Reference To MenuPopup Item
    '***************************************
    Return objMenuPopup
End Function
```

Answer (score 2):

I found [this link](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/macros/addingmenuitems.aspx) to be *very* useful.

Inside the OnConnection method, I had this:

```
CommandBars cmdBars = (CommandBars)applicationObject.CommandBars;
        CommandBar codeWindowCmdBar = cmdBars["Code Window"];

        CommandBarPopup doxygenPopup = (CommandBarPopup)codeWindowCmdBar.Controls.Add(MsoControlType.msoControlPopup,
                                    System.Reflection.Missing.Value,
                                    System.Reflection.Missing.Value, 
                                    1, 
                                    true);
        doxygenPopup.Caption = "Doxygen Commenting";


        CommandBarControl mnuListItem = (CommandBarControl)doxygenPopup.Controls.Add(MsoControlType.msoControlButton,
            System.Reflection.Missing.Value,
            System.Reflection.Missing.Value, 
            1, 
            true);

        mnuListItem.Caption = "Wrap as List Item";
        mnuListItemHandler = (CommandBarEvents) applicationObject.Events.get_CommandBarEvents(mnuListItem);
        mnuListItemHandler.Click += mnuListItemHandler_Click;

        CommandBarControl mnuUnorderedList = (CommandBarControl)doxygenPopup.Controls.Add(MsoControlType.msoControlButton,
            System.Reflection.Missing.Value,
            System.Reflection.Missing.Value,
            2,
            true);

        mnuUnorderedList.Caption = "Wrap as Unordered List";
        mnuUnorderedListHandler = (CommandBarEvents)applicationObject.Events.get_CommandBarEvents(mnuListItem);
        mnuUnorderedListHandler.Click += mnuUnorderedListHandler_Click;

        CommandBarControl mnuOrderedList = (CommandBarControl)doxygenPopup.Controls.Add(MsoControlType.msoControlButton,
            System.Reflection.Missing.Value,
            System.Reflection.Missing.Value,
            2,
            true);

        mnuOrderedList.Caption = "Wrap as Ordered List";
        mnuOrderedListHandler = (CommandBarEvents)applicationObject.Events.get_CommandBarEvents(mnuListItem);
        mnuOrderedListHandler.Click += mnuOrderedListHandler_Click;
```

Inside the click event handlers I did whatever was needed.

Please not that this was for a main menu item with sub items.  For just a single item, check out [this video](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/Video/bb614548).  The guy goes step by step...  Very well done.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `DTE.ExecuteCommand()` to execute other macros.